# Model binder crashes when validating values that dont parse

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been working in a web api 2.0 project which has a custom model binder to define which values should be assigned with a custom header for the authentication,now there is a problem that the model binder crashes whenever the nonnullable variable tries to be parsed, and it doesn't validates the property with Required attribute, the code for the first layer for the model binder is:

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType)
            {
                var x = context.Metadata as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata;
                var headerAttribute = x.Attributes.Attributes.Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(FromHeaderAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (headerAttribute != null)
                {
                    return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(HeaderComplexModelBinder));
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and for example if I send a null value it returns(instead going to the Required Attribute)

```
 "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-8f65cec15e936e4b88ecd7c5481064a3-9d837f90a296c748-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.cui": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int64. Path: $.cui| LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 43."
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using ASP.NET (Core) 5.0.2

Comment: The issue happens on the GetBinder method? Try to set a break point in the GetBinder method and then step by step to debug the code, whether you could get the data from the context and whether the data is correct? From the error message, the issue happens when convert the data to Int64 type, please check the json data and the model, whether the data type not match? Finally, can you share the related code about the model class, the json string in the http request and the action method with model binder? Then, we might according to your code to reproduce the problem and help you fix it.

Comment: @ZhiLv I assume it happens due to the custom binder I cant tell in which middleware the models is parsed  in my custom binder it isnt parsed

Comment: Have you ever set a break point in the GetBinder method to verify it? Based on the post code it is hard to reproduce the problem, I suggest you could share the related code about the model class, the custom model binder, the action method and the json string in the http request. Or you can create a simple sample to reproduce the problem, then we can check it and help you fix it.

Comment: Here are some relate article about using custom model binding, you can refer them: [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Custom Model Binding In ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/).